Clash between package -- nomencl and possibly polyglossia
I have an MWE that works fine if the lines on the package nomencl are commented out, but not with it in the mix:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{polya-en,
        author = {Pólya, George},
        title = {How to solve it},
        series = {Princeton Science Library},
        publisher = {Princeton University Press},
        address = {Princeton, N.J.},
        date = {2004},
        langid = {en},
        keywords = {pb},
}

@book{polya-ru,
        author = {Pólya, George},
        author-ru = {Пойа, Дьёрдь},
        title = {Как решать задачу},
        publisher = {Наука},
        date = {1959},
        address = {Москва},
        langid = {russian},
        keywords = {pb},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{russian}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmainfont[Script=Latin]{STIX Two Text}

\usepackage[refpage,intoc]{nomencl}
  \makenomenclature
  \renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}

%% Bibliographical citations:
\usepackage[style=authoryear,
%            language=auto,
            autolang=other,
            backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

It is possible to resolve it to be able to use nomencl?
I get an error:
! LaTeX Error: Command \autodot undefined.


See also this polyglossia issue report.

The bug in polyglossia has been fixed. An update is available. With polyglossia 2024/09/23 v2.3 the error does not longer happen and the original example works as expected. So I vote to close the question.

This is a bug in polyglossia. It uses \ifdef{\KOMAScript} as a test, whether it should redefine \autodot or not. But this is not a suitable test, because \KOMAScript is just a logo macro like \LaTeX or \TeX. See also the KOMA-Script documentation of \KOMAScript (I've highlighted the important sentence):

And indeed not only KOMA-Script classes define \KOMAScript. A better test whether \autodot is used would IMHO be to test for \autodot. And a better test for KOMA-Script classes is documented in the KOMA-Script documentation: Existence of macro \KOMAClassName. Once again a passage from the KOMA-Script documentation (I've again highlighted some important sentences):
And indeed not only KOMA-Script classes define \KOMAScript. A better test whether \autodot is used would IMHO be to test for \autodot. And a better test for KOMA-Script classes is documented in the KOMA-Script documentation: Existence of macro \KOMAClassName:

Update: The bug in polyglossia is fixed as suggested for the next release.
As a workaround you can try to use babel instead of polyglossia, because it seems to work:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{polya-en,
        author = {Pólya, George},
        title = {How to solve it},
        series = {Princeton Science Library},
        publisher = {Princeton University Press},
        address = {Princeton, N.J.},
        date = {2004},
        langid = {en},
        keywords = {pb},
}

@book{polya-ru,
        author = {Pólya, George},
        author-ru = {Пойа, Дьёрдь},
        title = {Как решать задачу},
        publisher = {Наука},
        date = {1959},
        address = {Москва},
        langid = {russian},
        keywords = {pb},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[russian,main=english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
%\setmainlanguage{english}
%\setotherlanguage{russian}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmainfont[Script=Latin]{STIX Two Text}

\usepackage[refpage,intoc]{nomencl}
  \makenomenclature
  \renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}

%% Bibliographical citations:
\usepackage[style=authoryear,
%            language=auto,
            autolang=other,
            backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

With babel additionally the usage of \babelfont would be possible:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{polya-en,
        author = {Pólya, George},
        title = {How to solve it},
        series = {Princeton Science Library},
        publisher = {Princeton University Press},
        address = {Princeton, N.J.},
        date = {2004},
        langid = {en},
        keywords = {pb},
}

@book{polya-ru,
        author = {Pólya, George},
        author-ru = {Пойа, Дьёрдь},
        title = {Как решать задачу},
        publisher = {Наука},
        date = {1959},
        address = {Москва},
        langid = {russian},
        keywords = {pb},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[russian,main=english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\babelfont[russian]{rm}{STIX Two Text}
\setmainfont[Script=Latin]{STIX Two Text}

\usepackage[refpage,intoc]{nomencl}
  \makenomenclature
  \renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}

%% Bibliographical citations:
\usepackage[style=authoryear,
%            language=auto,
            autolang=other,
            backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname}

\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}


A less serious solution would be to use a KOMA-Script class:
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{polya-en,
        author = {Pólya, George},
        title = {How to solve it},
        series = {Princeton Science Library},
        publisher = {Princeton University Press},
        address = {Princeton, N.J.},
        date = {2004},
        langid = {en},
        keywords = {pb},
}

@book{polya-ru,
        author = {Pólya, George},
        author-ru = {Пойа, Дьёрдь},
        title = {Как решать задачу},
        publisher = {Наука},
        date = {1959},
        address = {Москва},
        langid = {russian},
        keywords = {pb},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{russian}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmainfont[Script=Latin]{STIX Two Text}

\usepackage[refpage,intoc]{nomencl}
  \makenomenclature
  \renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}

%% Bibliographical citations:
\usepackage[style=authoryear,
%            language=auto,
            autolang=other,
            backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

because with KOMA-Script classes \autodot is always defined.
A more serious suggestion would be to add a \autodot dummy definition as workaround:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{polya-en,
        author = {Pólya, George},
        title = {How to solve it},
        series = {Princeton Science Library},
        publisher = {Princeton University Press},
        address = {Princeton, N.J.},
        date = {2004},
        langid = {en},
        keywords = {pb},
}

@book{polya-ru,
        author = {Pólya, George},
        author-ru = {Пойа, Дьёрдь},
        title = {Как решать задачу},
        publisher = {Наука},
        date = {1959},
        address = {Москва},
        langid = {russian},
        keywords = {pb},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{russian}
\providecommand*{\autodot}{}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmainfont[Script=Latin]{STIX Two Text}

\usepackage[refpage,intoc]{nomencl}
  \makenomenclature
  \renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}

%% Bibliographical citations:
\usepackage[style=authoryear,
%            language=auto,
            autolang=other,
            backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

or load nomencl before polyglossia:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{polya-en,
        author = {Pólya, George},
        title = {How to solve it},
        series = {Princeton Science Library},
        publisher = {Princeton University Press},
        address = {Princeton, N.J.},
        date = {2004},
        langid = {en},
        keywords = {pb},
}

@book{polya-ru,
        author = {Pólya, George},
        author-ru = {Пойа, Дьёрдь},
        title = {Как решать задачу},
        publisher = {Наука},
        date = {1959},
        address = {Москва},
        langid = {russian},
        keywords = {pb},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{russian}

\usepackage[refpage,intoc]{nomencl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmainfont[Script=Latin]{STIX Two Text}

\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}

%% Bibliographical citations:
\usepackage[style=authoryear,
%            language=auto,
            autolang=other,
            backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

But note, that this could breaks the redefinition of \@seccntformat in gloss-russian.ldf. Another workaround could be to undefine \KOMAScript:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{polya-en,
        author = {Pólya, George},
        title = {How to solve it},
        series = {Princeton Science Library},
        publisher = {Princeton University Press},
        address = {Princeton, N.J.},
        date = {2004},
        langid = {en},
        keywords = {pb},
}

@book{polya-ru,
        author = {Pólya, George},
        author-ru = {Пойа, Дьёрдь},
        title = {Как решать задачу},
        publisher = {Наука},
        date = {1959},
        address = {Москва},
        langid = {russian},
        keywords = {pb},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{russian}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmainfont[Script=Latin]{STIX Two Text}

\usepackage[refpage,intoc]{nomencl}
  \makenomenclature
  \renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}
  \let\KOMAScript\undefined

%% Bibliographical citations:
\usepackage[style=authoryear,
%            language=auto,
            autolang=other,
            backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

But this can also break others, e.g., if you want to print the KOMA-Script logo.
Because the official bugfix in polyglossia now replaces \KOMAScript by \KOMAClassName in gloss-russian.ldf (and gloss-hungarian.ldf), another (local) workaround would be, to edit the original files of your LaTeX distribution and do the same replacements (three times in gloss-russian.ldf and three times in gloss-hungarian.ldf). Usually it is not recommended to edit the original files, because the next update of the package would revert the change and your document would become incomatible with other installations. But in this case the replacement of the edited files with the next update of polyglossia is intended. Using a local (changed/updated) copy of only one file of a multi-file package in a local TEXMF root or the document folder is not recommended, because it is too easy to forget it, when either distributing the document source or updating the whole package.

Uauuu six solutions in total, that could be a record breaking. Would updating just gloss-russian.ldf and gloss-hungarian.ldf on my current TL installation be a plausible option? Or is that a bad idea ?

@TeXApprentice Using babel is a real option. Copying only one file is also only a workaround, “that could be a record breaking.” See the new paragraph at the end of my answer.

I could try babel but it would be a huge endeaveour, this project includes a Bibliography in 22 languages in 8 different scripts, two of them RtoL. I started with Babel a few years back, but at least at the start polyglossia seems to simplify most of the work.

@TeXApprentice babel support (not only) for RTL languages has been improved a lot in the last years. But if you don't want to use any tocbasic feature for nomencl (e.g. the option to use a numbered heading or a sublevel for the heading) and don't want to use another package that defines \KOMAScript, and don't want to use any other KOMA-Script package and don't want to wait for a polyglossia update have a look at egreg's answer.

The nomencl package, by default, loads tocbasic which is part of the KOMAScript suite.
The file gloss-russian.ldf checkes whether \KOMAScript is defined in order to make some decisions dependent on whether the document class is one of the KOMAScript suite. Clash.
Tell nomencl not to load tocbasic.
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{polya-en,
        author = {Pólya, George},
        title = {How to solve it},
        series = {Princeton Science Library},
        publisher = {Princeton University Press},
        address = {Princeton, N.J.},
        date = {2004},
        langid = {en},
        keywords = {pb},
}

@book{polya-ru,
        author = {Pólya, George},
        author-ru = {Пойа, Дьёрдь},
        title = {Как решать задачу},
        publisher = {Наука},
        date = {1959},
        address = {Москва},
        langid = {russian},
        keywords = {pb},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[refpage,intoc,notocbasic]{nomencl}

%% Bibliographical citations:
\usepackage[
  style=authoryear,
  %language=auto,
  autolang=other,
  backend=biber,
]{biblatex}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{russian}

\setmainfont[Script=Latin]{STIX Two Text}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{STIX Two Text}

\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}% <-- extension needed!

\defbibheading{bibliography}[\refname]{%
  \section*{#1}%
  \markboth{#1}{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\refname}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\nocite{*}

Abc\nomenclature{Abc}{Def}

\printbibliography

\printnomenclature

\end{document}

I recommend not to mix settings and package loading, see the edited preamble.
You don't need \selectlanguage{english}, as English is already declared as the main language. In order to add the bibliography to the table of contents, do like biblatex suggests.


Just two notes: 1) Loading package hvlogos (after \setotherlanguage{russian}) would result in the same error and does not use any KOMA-Script package. 2) With \setotherlanguage{russian} after loading nomencl (as shown in your example) option notocbasic is not needed. The main mistake is IMHO using the wrong test in polyglossia.

@cabohah Loading packages after setting the language is generally wrong, in my opinion. But removing notocbasic will make gloss-russian.ldf take the wrong paths, because \KOMAscript would be defined.  I fully agree that looking for \KOMAscript to be defined is not the best way to check whether the class is from the KOMAscript suite. If you really need hvlogos, just add \let\KOMAscript\relax after loading it.

It's \KOMAScript not \KOMAscript. And \let\KOMAScript\relax is not the best idea. If \KOMAScript is already used to show the KOMA-Script logo, this would instead show nothing.\let\KOMAScript\undefined would be better, so you would get a least an error message (and can then react on it). But this is more or less academic, because polyglossia is fixed now (see the link in my answer).

@cabohah Good to know. I still think that notocbasic is the best for nomencl anyway: people don't really want to use tocbasic, particularly not being informed about it.

User, who read the user manual should also be informed about the usage, because it is documented, that option tocbasic is the default and that this uses package tocbasic. And being able to use features of tocbasic for the nomenclature can be useful. To claim that users generally do not want to use tocbasic is therefore somewhat tendentious. But if you think so, you should do a feature request to make notocbasic the default.

Is this still an issue after the finx on polyglossia?

@TeXApprentice No, not for your issue. If you use another package, which is incompatible with tocbasic it can. But in several such cases you can instead use the user interface of tocbasic, i.e., to modify the ToC, LoF, LoT and similar entries. But this would be another question and should asked as new question, if you would have such a problem and cannot find an alternative yourself.
